# Which Data structure can be used for storing any unstructured XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, data-structures, xml-parsing, sax

I'm creating a tool which will take any XML as input and display it as a tree structure in the web page. Since anyone will be able to input their XML files to my tool, I will not know the XML schema in advance and I cannot create any JAXB classes. I will be parsing the XML using SAX parser and I need to store the contents of the XML in some data structure, so that I can do some processing on the XML data before I display it as a tree. But I'm not sure which data structure to use. I thought of using a Map of Maps kind of structure, but it becomes too complex. Could someone please suggest some ideas for the same ?

There is no code to share as it is still in the design phase.

EDITED:

This tool should display the XML elements as editable forms in the UI. The Element Names should be labels and the values should be displayed in an editable text box. Anyone should be able to edit the values and download the modified XML file. So I should parse the XML from java side and save it in some data structure and send it to UI, where I will be iterating the data structure and displaying it as an editable tree.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a DOM parser which has a data structure for any XML document. This has a data model for XML.

If you need to store all the information in it's original state, a SAX parser won't help you.